# php script generating new pw to PlayFab

Tags: php, playfab

This is my first php script ever and I have googled a lot to try to get the script to work.

I am working on this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/gaming/playfab/features/engagement/emails/using-email-templates-to-send-an-account-recovery-email

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>  
<html>
<head>
<style>
.error {color: #FF0000;}
</style>
</head>
<body>  

<?php
// define variables and set to empty values
$emailErr = $pw1Err = $pw2Err = "";
$email = $pw1 = $pw2 = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

  if (empty($_POST["email"])) 
  {
    $emailErr = "Email is required";
  } 
  else 
  {
    $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
    // check if e-mail address is well-formed
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
      $emailErr = "Invalid email format";
    }
  }

  if (empty($_POST["pw1"])) 
  {
    $pw1Err = "Password is required";
  }

  if (empty($_POST["pw2"])) {
    $pw2Err = "Confirm Password is required";
  }


//$str1 = "Hello";
//$str2 = "Hello World";
//echo strcasecmp($pw11, $pw2); // Outputs: -6


//$check = strcasecmp($pw11, $pw2)

$check = strcasecmp($pw1, $pw2); // Outputs: -6

/*
  if ($check == 0)
  {
      <br><br>
      echo Passwords are the same!;
      <br><br>
  }
  else
  {
      <br><br>
      echo Passwords are NOT the same!;
      <br><br>
  }
  */

}

function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}
?>

<h2>Password Recovery</h2>
<p><span class="error">* required field</span></p>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo     htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">  
  E-mail: <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo   $email;?>">
  <span class="error">* <?php echo $emailErr;?></span>
  <br><br>
  New Password: <input type="test_input" name=pw1 valur="<?php echo $pw1;?>">
  <span class="error">* <?php echo $pw1Err;?></span>
  <br><br>
  Confirm Password: <input type="test_input" name=pw2 valur="<?  php echo $pw2;?>">
  <span class="error">* <?php echo $pw2Err;?></span>
  <br><br><br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">  
</form>

<?php
echo "<br>";
echo "<h3>Your Input:</h3>";
echo $email;
echo "<br>";
echo $check;
?>

</body>
</html>
```

What I am trying to accomplish is the callback URL. I first tried to create it in WordPress, which was also a first, and now try with php code.

Here is what I try to accomplish:

A form with the following fields:

1. email
2. New pasword (currently a text_input during test but will be real pw)
3. Confirm password (currently a text_input during test but will be real pw)
4. Submit button

Currently I am focus on trying to echo the result but I just can't get this to work.

The ultimate target is to send back a confirmation with this API including the new checked password and the token.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/playfab/admin/account-management/reset-password?view=playfab-rest

I have been trying for quite a long time now so I reach out for help.

Comment: I missed the code but it is there now.

Comment: You never store `$_POST["pw1"]` in `$pw1`. Same for password 2.

Comment: Thanks, that took me at least one step further